# How to add to each object in an array a key-pair value based on each objects id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How can I add a key-pair value to each object in an array ( the array is a response from an ajax call )  based on the id of the object?

This is what I tried so far, but gives me undefined.

```
self.initialData = response.data.projectRequests.forEach(projectRequest => {
   Object.assign(projectRequest, "/view-project-team/" + projectRequest.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a key-value pair in an immutable way by doing this:

```
var pr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    data: "data"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    data: "data"
  }
]

console.log(pr);

var newPr = [];

pr.forEach(projectRequest => {
   newPr.push(Object.assign({}, projectRequest, {url: "/view-project-team/" + projectRequest.id}));
}); 

console.log(newPr);
```

Basically all you did wrong was the use of Object.assign(). It takes in an object width the values which should be added. You could also just have done this:

```
var pr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    data: "data"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    data: "data"
  }
]

pr.forEach(projectRequest => {
   Object.assign(projectRequest, {url: "/view-project-team/" + projectRequest.id});
});
```

To add the new key-value pair (in this case called "url").